# How can I write this in native JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML: `table>tr*3>td*5`. Some tags `<td>` have class `'some'`.
So the jQuery code is:

```
$('td').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('some'))
    alert('!');
});
```

How can I write this code in native JavaScript?

I tried this one but this doesn't work:

```
var target = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
target.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if ( target.hasAttributes('class', 'some') )
        alert('!');
});
```

Comment: This isn't a code conversion service. Show what you have tried that isn't working otherwise it's time for some research. You will get lots of help when you provide actual code rather than ask for people to do your work for you

Comment: We can't fire click event like Jquery. On HTML tag it self we have to mention onClick = functionName();. Call this function on click.

Comment: @Samir that is the old school way of doing it. This isn't the 1990's

Comment: @RedArtz can you paste the failing attempt into the question?

Comment: Ok..so main issue with your approach is `target` is a collection and you have to iterate collection and apply listener to each instance

Comment: I know @charlietfl, the question is how to write the same click event in JavaScript. Hence that one is my replay.

Comment: Please try to search first, then post the answer...you will find lots of answer related to this. by the way you can add event by core javascript using addEventListener("event",Your handler)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it as:

```js
var td = document.querySelectorAll('td');

for (t of td) {
  t.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.classList.contains('red')) {
      console.log(this.className,'!');
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.red { color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}
.blue { color: rgb(0, 255, 0);}
.green { color: rgb(0, 0, 255);}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='red'>Red</td>
    <td class='blue'>Blue</td>
    <td class='green'>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='red'>Red</td>
    <td class='blue'>Blue</td>
    <td class='green'>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='red'>Red</td>
    <td class='blue'>Blue</td>
    <td class='green'>Green</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all a lot! I've code it my own with your help. This code work for me:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i = 0; i<elements.length;i++){
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (this.hasAttributes('class','some') ) {
            alert('!');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code is not working because the query you are making does not return a single value as there are multiple td's (it returns an Array of HTMLCollection)
2. You can avoid all this by simply adding an eventListener on their parent (tr or table) and then using e.target to check the target clicked and place your logic there.

here is a much more efficient example with fully native JS.

```
var table = document.querySelector('table');

table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if(target.tagName === "TD" && target.classList.contains('some') ) {
    alert('!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps, something like this should do:

```
var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('td'));
elements.forEach(function (element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (element.classList.indexOf('some') >= 0) {
            alert('!');
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: changed it, thanks!

Comment: In other words...`elements` isn't an array .... it's an array like object that has length but can't use array methods on it directly